# BasicHttpBinding over Load Balancer SSL Endpoint client is http, while service is expecting https

Tags: wcf, http, ssl, https, binding

So I have this wcf service I cannot change, it uses basicHttpBinding for its communication. When this is used internally it works like a charm. The problem is  that I'm trying to expose this service to the public, but the service is behind a load balancer that forces HTTPS/SSL. This basicHttpBinding will not work and it because of the url transformation and setting the transport to equal transport does will not work either.

Currently this is my Client bindings:

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);

basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
```

Not quite sure if the last parts are needed, seems to throw the same error regardless.

And the Proxy Service I'm Creating looks like this:

```
  <!-- DOWNLOAD HTTP -->
  <service name="ArchiveServiceValidation" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint
      address=""
      contract="ArchiveService.IArchiveService"
      name="ArchiveServiceValidationHTTP"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTP"/>

    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTP"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>

  <!-- DOWNLOAD HTTPS -->
  <service name="ArchiveServiceValidationHTTPS" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint
      address=""
      contract="ArchiveService.IArchiveService"
      name="ArchiveServiceValidationHTTPS"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTPS"/>

    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTPS"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>


 <client>
  <endpoint
    address="http://url-that-has-to-be-http-no-matter-what-i-do.com"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTP"
    contract="ArchiveService.IArchiveService"
    name="DownloadDocumentEndpoint">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
 </client>
```

Here is the bindings that I've set up to work for both HTTP and HTTPS.

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" name="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTPS">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5000000" />
    </binding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" name="BasicHttpBinding_IArchiveService_HTTP">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="500000000" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

And my metadata behaviours configs:

```
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add port="80" scheme="http"/>
          <add port="443" scheme="https"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
    </behavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

Fixed the problem for me, it turned out to be 2 placed in my client where I used the BasicHttpBinding